# What makes a user want to engage heavily into the application?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, design

I have recently been working on a desktop application, however I don't think "what" the application does is really important for this discussion.  When I ask what makes the user want to engage in the application I mean what is it that presents the "WOW" factor?  Is it the buttons, the design(colors, shapes, etc..), and/or transition from page to page in the application?

I know when I'm using an application the professionalism always makes me check it out even more.  So then this leads me to is it the professionalism in the user experience that attracts people?  Take Apple and iOS for example.  The look and feel isn't silly, outrageous, or outdated.

So is it the professionalism?  The variations in the design?

Comment: You need to form as a straight question. As of now, it feels like open thoughts being voiced out. As for what I understand out of it, it the entire package. You can not readily dissect it by buttons, colors etc. It comprises of workflows, number of clicks, understanding of user's mental models as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### User experience is different from usability

Although this might be obvious, it provides a useful distinction for understanding how to design delightful user experience.

- One well-reasoned framework used by Aaron Walter (author of [Designing for Emotions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1937557006)) is the **hierarchy of user needs** which is based on the similar logic to [Maslow's Hierarchy of Needs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow%27s_hierarchy_of_needs):

  [image: hierarchy of needs]
- The pyramid outlines key conditions for creating pleasurable design:

  1. To create pleasurable design, an application must first be usable.
  2. To create usable design, an application must first be functional and reliable. An unrealiable application cannot be usable!
  3. Usability is not enough.
- Once you are satisfied that a design incorporates a suitable level of usability, reliability and functionality, you can focus on designing for user delight and pleasure.

  [image: usable vs pleasurable]
- Design for pleasure is complicated. At the core of this process, it's important to understand what makes users happy and to tailor design to evoke those feelings.

  - An understand of this core process helps drive design decisions around color, layout, UX flow, interactions, and design details.
- There are too many specific processes and frameworks for delightful design for a StackExchange question to reasonably cover, so I'd instead suggest starting with the following resources:

  - [UX Myth:  Design is about Usability](http://uxmyths.com/post/1533970267/myth-27-ux-design-is-about-usability)
  - [Is there a formula for delight?](http://uxmastery.com/formula-delight/)
  - [Seductive Interaction Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321725522)
  - [Emotional Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465051367)

Answer (score 3):

Function before form. People will use garbage -- and often do -- if the application is good. The better the application, the more likely I am to use it, and to continue using it. Form only comes into question when it stops people from utilizing the application or when there are multiple competitors on the market with the same function(s).

Your example of iOS is a good one. People come to it because it's clean, looks nice and organized, and it is in fact very comforting because of the level of precision Apple put into the OS. Things like icons have very precise measurements. That's why fanboys go crazy when the calendar app has a number one pixel off from perfectly centered. But what makes people use iOS daily is the behaviors and ease-of-use, not the clean look. That's why so many people switch to iOS from Android: the environment is easier to do the things they want a smartphone to do.

That's also why so many people prefer Android: Apple is closed and locks a lot of the functions that others take for granted.

So really your question is what makes people come to you in the first place, and that depends on your product, demographic, and market. As for what makes them stay...build the thing that people want to use.

Comment: "when there are multiple competitors on the market with the same function(s)" Nowadays, there are always others in the market with same functions. Or after two months they have same functions. Form aka usability is a must-have as well as functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path!
The so called hedonic qualities are the WOW-factors of your application.
But, there are also some costs of use, which is usability. Usability has to be good, otherwise users avoid your app. This is the baseline (or must-have). Nobody would buy your app, because it is usable. People expect it!

If your must-have is good, you can put the nice-to-have on top, like the look and feel.

For your question "*When I ask what makes the user want to engage in the application*" take a look at this research paper "*Factors Influencing Adoption and Post-Adoption of Smart Phone*". It says what factors are important for first use und regular use: http://ipcsit.com/vol9/20-B009.pdf

And this one "*Ux over time*" which is *An exploratory study aimed at understanding how users form evaluative judgments during the first experiences with a product as well as after four weeks of use* at:
http://www.researchgate.net/publication/221514162_User_experience_over_time

Answer (score 2):

Since question is stated in a way it can be answerd vaguely best answer would be that it depends on combination of any number of factors. However, if we take [Dieter Rams' 10 principles for good design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieter_Rams) and apply them to application design we can outline list of major factors that impact applications user engagement:

**1. Is innovative**

App should be following or even setting trends in design (ie. Flat or Material design) and technology

**2. Makes a product useful**

It addresses users pain points and evokes positive feelings by highlighting critical bussiness workflow with its features and performance

**3. Is aesthetic**

Overall look and feel should be modern, pleasing and not feel outdated

**4. Makes a product understandable**

Purpose of the app should be clear and all features easily understandable by the user without need for long instructions and manuals.

**5. Is unobtrusive**

App should help improve users workflow and not stand in his way (ie. have predefined default settings and make educated choices for user when possible). [Don' Make Me Think](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321344758) is good resource on this topic that also ties to next point.

**6. Is honest**

All inputs, links and buttons trigger expected actions and behavior. Also, app should fulfill everything that may be said in marketing campaigns and ads (deliver on promises and expectations).

**7. Is long-lasting**

App is proven useful over time. This can be further empahiszed by having an established brand and large customer base (think Apple).

This can also mean for development team they should be adressing bugs and technical debt in timely manner, before adding new features.

**8. Is thorough down to the last detail**

UI is polished and enhanched with minor non-critical details that add value to overall expirience (again Apple and also examples [from here](http://littlebigdetails.com/)).

**9. Is environmentally friendly**

It works and integrates well across range of devices - desktops, phones, watches etc.

**10. Is as little design as possible**

Not over designed or cluttered with bunch of non-critical features and options that will stand in the way of user workflow.